# Jetson TX2 OpenCV GStreamer-CRITICAL error

Tags: java, opencv, gstreamer, nvidia, nvidia-jetson

I'm trying now to fix this bug for a few days and nothing is going forward..
I want to acces the camera of my Nvidia Jetson Tx2 with OpenCV and GStreamer.

> (java:7468): GStreamer-CRITICAL **:gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

```
 Videocapture cap = new VideoCapture();
cap.open("nvcamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1280, height=
(int)720, format=(string)I420, framerate=(fraction)120/1 ! nvvidconv flip-
method=2 ! video/x-raw, format=(string)I420 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=
(string)BGR ! appsink");
    cap.read(...
```

This pipeline worked great, but as I started my Jetson a few days ago it gave me this error. Maybe because I updated something... I don't know

**Information**

- Nvidia Jetson TX2
- Ubuntu 16.04
- OpenCV 3.4.2
- Java 1.8
- GStreamer + plugins installed

Tried to rebuild OpenCV but nothing helped

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Run `gst-inspect-1.0` and check if all elements you used in that pipeline are listed there.

Comment: Hi, I checked all elements but everything is installed.. Sry I didn't went to stackoverflow since yesterday

Comment: Hi, could you share more of your error log. It is better to see which element fails.

Comment: Hey, I already searched for the error log but I didn't found it. Do you know where the error log is? I'm using netbeans btw

Comment: one of the elements you are using does not exist. Or maybe there is a typo in the element name in your pipeline. Check all the elements using `gst-inspect`

Comment: I found all elements using gst-inspect-1.0

Comment: You could [activate GStreamer logging](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gst-running.html) to find out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at pipelines from deepstream samples, on jetson nano they have extra element in pipeline **nvegltransform**. Its really hard to understand from their documents what it is, but may be you should try it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example pipeline that worked for me:

```html
cv2.VideoCapture((
  "nvarguscamerasrc ! "
  "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), "
  "width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, "
  "format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)%d/1 ! "
  "nvvidconv flip-method=%d ! "
  "video/x-raw, width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, format=(string)BGRx ! "
  "videoconvert ! "
  "video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink "
  "wait-on-eos=false drop=true max-buffers=1"
  % (
      capture_width,
      capture_height,
      framerate,
      flip_method,
      display_width,
      display_height,
  )
), cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```